# Multiple One-Class SVMs for Multiclass Classification with an additional "Unknown" Class

Tags: classification, svm, one-class-classification

I am in a sound event classification setting, using a traditional SVM model on acoustic indicators calculated from raw audio.
I have 3 classes I want to be able to identify, say A, B and C, but also a potential number of other events that I haven't heard yet. So I have 3 well-defined classes and a third one that would be "Unknown" and thus as wide as sound events that could occur in this particular environment.

To take a more illustrative example, let's say we are trying to identify Dogs, Cats and Birds in a natural environment, from the noise recorded from a microphone. The microphone being in an environment that also features Monkeys, Deers, Sheeps, etc... (strange environment isn't it?)

My first approach is to use a OneVsRest or OneVsOne strategy, considering the "Unknown" class as another well-defined class. But wouldn't training three OneClass SVM models be a better approach? That would mean doing three inferences each time and potentially time consuming, but with better results. That would basically mean training 3 different outliers detectors.

What is your take on this?

Many thanks in advance.

Cheers

Antoine